# Facebook login + Firebase + Xcode 8 & Swift 3. ERROR

Tags: facebook, swift3, firebase-authentication

Xcode keeps complaining about an ambigous reference I've made in the AppDelegate. I'm trying to integrate Facebook Login with Firebase in my Xcode project using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxYpuUH53L4).

**Error:**

> Ambiguous reference to member 
>   'application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)'

**Code:**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase
import FBSDKLoginKit


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        FIRApp.configure()
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        return true
    }

private func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey) -> Bool {
    var handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey], annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]) // Error happens here
    // Add any custom logic here.
    return handled
}
```

I'm not sure what what this error means (still new to iOS programming). I've highlighted where it happens in the code with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import CoreData
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FIRApp.configure()
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, _: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {

        let handled: Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
        return handled
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Hi Mario. Thx for the suggestion. Have tried to implement the code snippet in my Xcode project. I get the same error :/

Comment: sorry i'm not a pro class and i got the same problem and this code solve for my project i think the error generate only on swift 3